# Pass dynamic url parameter for flask url_for

Tags: python, flask

I have the below URL's mapping to one form:

```
<a href="/home/downloads/application_one">Download Application</a>
<a href="/home/downloads/application_two">Download Application</a>
<a href="/home/downloads/application_three">Download Application</a>
<a href="/home/downloads/application_four">Download Application</a>

<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('home.downloads') }}">
```

How do I pass

```
application_one, application_two, application_three, application_four
```

dynamically to "url_for" in form?

This is my route:

```
@download.route('/downloads/<application_name>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def downloads(application_name):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass it as second argument to `url_for`

```
{{ url_for('home.downloads', application_name = "YOUR DYNAMIC APP NAME") }}
```

Edit:

For the dynamic one, you simply pass the variable.

```
{{ url_for('home.downloads', application_name = application) }}
```

and when you are rendering the template, send your dynamic value.

```
     application = "DO WHATEVER AND ASSIGN THE VALUE HERE"
     return render_template("template.html", application = application )
```

Refer: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/quickstart/#url-building